# Compiler thinks the times* operand is a pointer

Tags: objective-c

Here's the line with the error:

```
player.legalMoney = ((player.wealth * 3000) + arc4random() % (player.luck * 1000)) / difficulty;
```

I'm getting the error 'invalid operands to binary expression ('int *' and 'int') on both the *'s in the line.

Here is the interface section:

```
{
    int *legalMoney, *wealth, *luck;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) *legalMoney, *wealth, *luck;
```

I assume the problem is the compiler thinking the * is a pointer, so if I change it to:

```
player.legalMoney = ((*player.wealth * 3000) + arc4random() % (*player.luck * 1000)) / difficulty;
```

then there is no compiling errors, but a runtime error: "Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x0)

Comment: Don't declare your int as a pointer.  Legalmoney, wealth, and luck are simple types and shouldn't be made into pointers on the heap for your purposes.  Also, property declaration should be declared with a type, presumably an int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to multiply pointers with numbers. You should derefence pointers to get to their values, so your second example is correct.

`player.wealth` returns the pointer to a memory location holding an int with the value
`*player.wealth` returns the actual value stored at the memory location

But your real issue is that you are declaring pointers to integers instead of integer values, which is probably not what you intented. It should be declared as:

```
{
    int legalMoney, wealth, luck;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) int legalMoney;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int wealth;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int luck;
```

Then you can use your original code:

```
player.legalMoney = ((player.wealth * 3000) 
                         + arc4random() % (player.luck * 1000)) / difficulty;
```

Comment: This fixed my problem, but it seem's that @Jan Dvorak was right, I'm not initialising the properties correctly, they are coming back as 0. I'll have to see what's going on there.

Comment: @PappaSmalls well, I can't see why they _should_ be pointers.

Comment: Indeed, you shouldn't use pointers at all, unless you intented to use real objects like NSNumber. Integral data types like int aren't normally declared as pointers (read a good book about plain C, and you'll learn a great deal about pointers, maybe more than you ever wanted to learn)

Answer (score 1):

Your instance variables are pointers to `int`s (`int*`), and your property returns a pointer to an int. You should make your instance variables plain integers, and the properties should return plain integers.